# Try to learn about shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I try to learn a new skill for shell script. So now I receive a lesson from my teacher about move file to new directory.

## Question

There is a file pattern

```
A_20180423_0015  B_20180501_0045  C_20180426_0045
```

and want to moving files to those directories like /new/destpath/A/20180423/0015,0030,0045 each directory have a 3 files

in my script i write

```
 #! /bin/bash
cd /app/Moving/DEST_PATH
mkdir A B C D
cd /app/Moving/DEST_PATH/A
MakesubA=$(for itype in A;do for ((i=1;i<=10;i++));do for ((itime=15;itime<=45;itime=itime+15));do mkdir ${itype}_$(date --date "${i} day ago" +"%Y%m%d")_00${itime} ;done;done;done)
cd ..
cd /app/Moving/DEST_PATH/B
MakesubB=$(for itype in B;do for ((i=1;i<=10;i++));do for ((itime=15;itime<=45;itime=itime+15));do mkdir ${itype}_$(date --date "${i} day ago" +"%Y%m%d")_00${itime} ;done;done;done)
cd ..
cd /app/Moving/DEST_PATH/C
MakesubC=$(for itype in C;do for ((i=1;i<=10;i++));do for ((itime=15;itime<=45;itime=itime+15));do mkdir ${itype}_$(date --date "${i} day ago" +"%Y%m%d")_00${itime} ;done;done;done)
cd ..
cd /app/Moving/DEST_PATH/D
MakesubD=$(for itype in D;do for ((i=1;i<=10;i++));do for ((itime=15;itime<=45;itime=itime+15));do mkdir ${itype}_$(date --date "${i} day ago" +"%Y%m%d")_00${itime} ;done;done;done)
cd ..
```

and i try to figure it out to use loop or it else but i don't know which use to select each file to each directory.

Comment: Can you add some more details about what exactly the pattern is, where the files are currently stored, and how the target structure will look like (an example would help a lot here)? Also, do you need `MakesubA` later on in your script for something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have files that basically have a destination path encoded in their filenames.

The file called `A_20180423_0015` should be moved to `A/20180423/0015` (I'm assuming `0015` is the new name of the file in the directory `A/20180423`), which is a pathname that is the same as the original filename but with the underscores replaced by slashes.

This means that this exercise is about replacing characters in strings.

There is no need to go through and create destination directories for every single possible date because the destination is already encoded in the filename of the files.

I'm not entirely sure where the original files are located, or whether you can just use `[A-Z]_*_*` as a pattern to match them in the current directory (I'm going to assume you can).

```
for source_filename in [A-Z]_*_*; do
    target_pathname=${source_filename//_//}
    mkdir -p "${target_pathname%/*}"
    mv "$source_filename" "$target_pathname"
done
```

If we start out with

```
.
|-- A_20180423_0015
|-- B_20180501_0045
`-- C_20180426_0045

0 directory, 3 files
```

... and run the above code, then we'll end up with

```
.
|-- A/
|   `-- 20180423/
|       `-- 0015
|-- B/
|   `-- 20180501/
|       `-- 0045
`-- C/
    `-- 20180426/
        `-- 0045

6 directories, 3 files
```

Annotated code:

```
# Loop over all names in the current directory that matches the given pattern.
for source_filename in [A-Z]_*_*; do
    # Replace all underscores in the found name with slashes.
    # We use bash's ${parameter//pattern/replacement} pattern substitution
    # to do this.
    # If you need to append a path to this, just do so with
    #    target_pathname="/some/path/${source_filename//_//}"
    target_pathname=${source_filename//_//}

    # Make sure that the target directory exists.
    # With ${target_pathname%/*} we remove the filename component of
    # the target pathname to get the directory of the destination file.
    # You may change this to the following if you wish:
    #     mkdir -p "$( dirname "$target_pathname" )"
    mkdir -p "${target_pathname%/*}"

    # Move the file into place.
    mv "$source_filename" "$target_pathname"
done
```

---

If I have misunderstood the question and the files should retain their original filenames, but be moved into directories corresponding to the filename, i.e. `A_20180423_0015` should be moved to `A/20180423/0015/A_20180423_0015`, then we only have to change a few characters in the code above:

```
mkdir -p "${target_pathname%/*}"
```

changes to

```
mkdir -p "$target_pathname"
```

This change would give us

```
.
|-- A/
|   `-- 20180423/
|       `-- 0015/
|           `-- A_20180423_0015
|-- B/
|   `-- 20180501/
|       `-- 0045/
|           `-- B_20180501_0045
`-- C/
    `-- 20180426/
        `-- 0045/
            `-- C_20180426_0045

9 directories, 3 files
```

---

For the case when the source files are located in another directory than the current one:

```
for source_pathname in /some/source/path/[A-Z]_*_*; do
    source_filename=${source_pathname##*/}
    target_pathname="some/target/path/${source_filename//_//}"
    mkdir -p "$target_pathname"
    mv "$source_pathname" "$target_pathname"
done
```

Comment: I try to adapt a script like add a path on source_file and target folder
but result is
A  B  C  D  DEST_PATH  
folder A B C D not in a folder target folder

Comment: @Dnop Sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying. Do you need to access the original files in another location than the current directory?

Comment: Yes.
This is a adapt script, I add a path for source_file and target file

#for source_filename in /app/D_GRPAH/TEST_GRAPH/LAB2/[A-Z]_*_*; do
#    target_pathname="/app/D_GRAPH/TEST_GRAPH/DEST_PATH/${source_filename//_//}"
#    mkdir -p "${target_pathname}"
#    mv "$source_filename" "$target_pathname"
#done

but it not work

Comment: @Dnop See updated answer.

Comment: If i add a path, script is error
[serveradm@DSNJENKA002G TEST_GRAPH]$ bash movefile.bash 
mv: cannot stat €/app/D_GRPAH/TEST_GRAPH/LAB2/[A-Z]_*_*€: No such file or directory

but if i don't add a path. It work on your shell script but i try add a path
#for source_filename in [A-Z]_*_*; do
#   target_pathname="/app/D_GRAPH/TEST_GRAPH/${source_filename//_//}"
#   mkdir -p "$target_pathname"
#   mv "$source_filename" "$target_pathname"
#done
a result folder A B C D. It isn't in a DEST_PATH.

Comment: @Dnop The error messages says `D_GRPAH`. Did you mistype the path?

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Kusalananda I will try find a way to complete a script. :D